# Dead link in link-only answer to lock, historical question

Tags: support, specific-question, historical-lock

The question "[What's the strangest corner case you've seen in C# or .NET?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/194484/)" has been closed and locked, because it's a poll (*not constructive*) but has historical significance to this site.

The problem is, one of the [answers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/195808/469708) is a link-only answer with a dead link:

> **When is a Boolean neither True nor False?**
>
> Bill discovered that you can hack a boolean so that if A is True and B is True,
>   (A and B) is False.
>
> [Hacked Booleans](http://msmvps.com/blogs/bill/archive/2004/06/23/8730.aspx)

Without the link, the answer is completely useless. But since the question is locked, I cannot add a comment or flag the question. What to do?

Comment: *"the question is closed and locked"* - why bother?

Comment: You leave it be, or nominate the whole question for deletion here on Meta. It is locked; the notice tells you that stuff will be outdated.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Actually, the notice does not say that. It just says that this type of question is not appropriate anymore.

Comment: @SebastianNegraszus: *This question and its answers are frozen and cannot be changed*.

Comment: "How can I make A and B both True, but (A and B) false in C# <version>" sounds like a good candidate for a self-answered SO question, if you can find the original article back. (Didn't find it in archive.org :-( )

Comment: The link seems to be working now.

Answer (score -3):

The historical lock notice tells you:

> This question and its answers are frozen and cannot be changed.

That means that the whole post is frozen in time, and will atrophy more and more as the years pass. Links will break, information will be outdated, etc.

If and when the post has no longer any use, we can elect to delete it entirely. Raise a post here on Meta making the case, and we can discuss that. Until that point however, the post remains frozen and the link cannot be fixed.