# Please undelete this highly-upvoted PHP question

Tags: discussion, specific-question, deleted-questions, old-questions, recommendation-questions

Please look at [PHP tutorial that is security-, accuracy- and maintainability-conscious?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2119083/php-tutorial-that-is-security-accuracy-and-maintainability-conscious).

The question has a lot of info for everyone and that is helpful. The question itself looks to me like a tutorial for every php programmer.

I want to this question/discussion visible for everyone, guys, after all this is helpful for the community and that's why we are here.

[Link to image for <10K](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sGkY3.jpg)

Comment: tutorial? From the title, I can say this looks like a bad question.... Anyway, at 40K, can't you vote to undelete yourself?

Comment: @Patrice I expect he already has.

Comment: Any chance of a screenshot for <10K?

Comment: @servy me too, my point is that this is how he should reopen. Harnessing the meta effect isn't a good idea

Comment: @Patrice: I did so but I cant open alone. Don't you think that is helpful

Comment: @ShaktiSingh I can't see the question. The title alone sounds like off topic. And you voted to reopen? then wait and let the system work.

Comment: Question is *clearly* asking for a tutorial and so **now** off-topic under current guidelines.

Comment: @KevinB This is necessary so that people can go there and judge once. who knows when the get be redirected on that question.

Comment: @Paulie_D That was off topic even when it was asked.

Comment: @ShaktiSingh I can't see it, but just being "helpful" doesn't mean "on-topic" or "appropriate for SO".  The title alone makes me think that it isn't a good SO question.

Comment: It's a whole bunch of link-only answers, or answers stating that such tutorials can't be done. Just grab the links yourself and when valuable, use them to improve your tag wiki or host them somewhere else.

Comment: @resueman Nothing interesting there.  Question asking for tutorials, has a ton of link only answers, was deleted.

Comment: @resueman http://imgur.com/oL4D8yQ

Comment: Surely you've seen how awful the answers are. Why would you want this reopened? How is a collection of link-only answers useful to anyone? It's only going to attract more of the same.

Comment: @vaultah thx... this is actually WORSE than the title made it sound :S

Comment: @KevinB: The question itself looks me useful but not the answers let us put some more valuable answers on that question.

Comment: Not only is this question completely off-topic, it is no longer even correct. The question explicitly states that it is looking for a tutorial that will teach the proper use of the deprecated `mysql_*` functions.

Comment: If the question in all these years didn't get us useful answers ... why would now be any different? It's a poor question (by current standards) inviting poor answers.

Comment: @meagar: You have just picked up a negative thing from a list of positive points.

Comment: Then pick out the gems and formulate your own **on topic** question regarding the issues you're interested in.

Comment: That one negative alone makes it not suitable to being reopened. Why should the other points even be considered.

Comment: Please stop rolling back the edits. There's absolutely no need for the same link to appear twice.

Comment: Just what information is there that is not already covered (and maintained) here https://github.com/vhf/free-programming-books/blob/master/free-programming-books.md#php?

Comment: @Braiam no, for example http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/PHP_and_HTML_Forms (two clicks away) displays many of the issues that the original question tried to address.

Comment: @CodeCaster "PHP Essentials" is on the list ¬_¬

Comment: @Braiam not sure if you read the question that this question is about, but it's about tutorials that don't contain common errors. Using `echo $_POST[...]` is such an error. Those should not be in tutorials.

Comment: @CodeCaster are you reading my *first* comment? What information provides that Q&A that isn't covered in the materials on the FPB repository?

Comment: @Braiam the point is not "being covered in". The entire cry-out in the post we're talking about here is that so many tutorials show code that breaks your site or exposes your database. In a mere two clicks, I found proof of that in the link you so wittingly provided. It is an error to use `echo $_POST[...]`, and that tutorial does it - without even mentioning why you should never output user input like that. So, it is a prime example of what the OP of that question was **not** looking for. It is irrelevant that somewhere else in the same site the subject _is_ handled: the example is flawed.

Comment: @CodeCaster and your point is? The only thing I know is that if you find a flaw on the links I "wittingly provided" you can easily fix them. On the other hand, through I can't see where the links go in the deleted question, how many of those can you actually fix?

Comment: @Braiam my point is that I really don't know what you're trying to prove with that link. OP of the discussed question was looking for PHP tutorials that do not show quite specific traits. You provided a link to a list of PHP tutorials, where the first one that I clicked on shows one of the traits that good tutorials should not display. In other words: OP was looking for non-sucking tutorials, and you link to tutorials that suck. Your link is irrelevant, and so is the fact that "anyone can edit them": as of now, they are spreading misinformation and inarguably broken and even harmful code.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Please stop closing useful questions](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/310169/please-stop-closing-useful-questions)

Answer (score -3, accepted):

While it was *ok'ish* to have questions asking for tutorials when the question was asked, it is no longer so nowadays. Quoting from our Off-Topic reasons:

> Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it.

As others have already pointed out, most of answers point off-site, while we want information to be on-site. I wouldn't be surprised if most of the links are dead by now, leaving the answers obsolete. Keeping the question deleted is probably the best thing to do.

Then again, badge-wise, this is a Famous Question (10k+ views) and a Great Question (100 upvotes; of which we have 12312 in total) with a Great Answer (100 upvotes; of which we have 27716 in total). Of the 10 million visible questions on SO, only 7k have 295+ upvotes. It also has a sizeable number of favorites. It certainly wouldn't get these figures nowadays, but I guess it was valuable/useful to the community back then. So if a mod wants to be nice to the requester, he could probably justify undeleting *and* [locking it for historical purposes](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/126587):

> A historical lock preserves older content that was very popular when it was originally posted, but is now off-topic or otherwise out of scope for the site it is posted on. Historically locking a post ends the debate over whether a question should be kept on the site or deleted, and is often the final state of a question that has been deleted and undeleted more than once.

We did so for similar link-only questions in the past. For instance [C++ blogs that you regularly follow?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/151974)

Again, not saying a mod *should* do that; just *could*.

Comment: Questions are only historically locked when they're of *extremely* high value.  This post is absolutely not of very high value.

Comment: Locking a question prevents even trying to fix it, by either downvoting answers or editing out security issues.

Comment: @Servy FWIW, badge-wise, this is a Famous Question (10k+ views) and a Great Question (100 upvotes; of which we have 12312 in total) with a Great Answer (100 upvotes; of which we have 27716 in total). Of the 10 million visible Qs on SO, only 7k have 295+ upvotes. It certainly wouldn't get these nowadays, but I guess it was historically significant by these numbers. Note that I am not saying it *should* get undeleted, but if a mod wants to be nice to the requester, he probably *could* justify locking it. That's all I am saying. Note that my answer clearly states that it's OT.

Comment: @PeeHaa yes, it would. Fair argument against it.

Comment: @Gordon The views and votes doesn't mean that the question is useful.  It means that it was (once) popular.  I can't see how a mod could possibly justify the extremely high bar that this question would need to meet to be historically significant.  The fact that the terrible question has a lot of views doesn't make it not a terrible question.  Historical locks are there for posts of high value, not posts with a high view count.

Comment: @Servy Popularity is a *result* of the votes and views, but not the meaning itself. Votes are there to indicate usefulness. My reading of http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/126587 and http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/272142/dead-link-in-link-only-answer-to-lock-historical-question suggests that locking for historical significance would be justified. But feel free to disagree.

Comment: @Gordon Votes are *supposed* to indicate usefulness.  In actuality they indicate popularity, which has some correlation to usefulness, but there are exceptions, such as the case here.  A post having a lot of votes is a sign that it's more likely to be useful than a post without a lot of votes.  That doesn't mean it is necessarily useful.  *This post has literally zero useful information in it*.  It in no way meets the bar for historical significance as *one of the most useful posts on the site* when it *has no useful information at all*.

Comment: @Servy I disagree with your view on votes. I agree that the post has zero information "in it". But it's a question from "back then". And "back then" we didn't have the same strict standards we have now. It did have value back then. Also note that it was only closed two years after it was asked. I checked the links in the highest voted answer and they still work. So it does still have some value by collecting these. Not good enough for today, but good enough for historical. Again, feel free to disagree.

Comment: @PeeHaa regarding not being able to fix it: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/272142/dead-link-in-link-only-answer-to-lock-historical-question

Comment: @Gordon We only historically lock posts that are of enormous value to us *right now*.  I don't see that content as being enormously useful even back then, but that's a pointless argument anyway.  If you think that it's not useful now, then it in no way merits a historical lock.  That tool is in place *to prevent the deletion of useful content* even though that content doesn't follow the rules.  Since there's no useful content here, there's no problem with it being deleted.

Comment: @Servy I never claimed there is a problem with it being deleted. I actually supported that it is.

Comment: @Gordon You're saying that historically locking it would be appropriate.  The whole point of historically locking a post is to prevent it from being deleted.

Comment: @Servey then you are misreading my answer. It clearly says it should probably stay as is.

Answer (score 35):

The top answer is Not An Answer and is nothing more than a few links to external resources.

The second highest answer is an answer that is only explaining why the question can't be answered (<3 the irony).

The rest are mostly just more link only answer posts.

This question isn't actually adding value.  There is no information actually in that question, just links to information **already accessible to people**, even when that question is deleted.

Comment: In addition, very nearly all the answers have commentary from the OP stating that the proffered resource does not meet the criteria he laid out in the question.

Comment: Go look up what NAA is.

Comment: @user193661 seems to fit the most upvoted answer pretty well; removing the markup that makes the links links results in an answer that doesn't give an answer to the question. It is a signpost, not an answer.

Answer (score 23):

> this question has a lot of info for everyone and that is helpful

No, it doesn't.

It contains an extremely valid problem statement: all online tutorials suck*. That's an unfortunate truth, but not one that can be solved in one or more Stack Overflow answers: too broad.

The question then proceeds to ask for tutorials that don't suck: off-topic, because off-site resources.

There is one also very valid answer:

> The "tutorial" you dream about is made of years of learning the basics and even more years of such tiny bits.

The remaining the answers link to tutorials that may or may not be online anymore, and that may or may not display the issues that OP tried to address.

This question and its answers are *not* a valuable addition to the site, and I would *not* vote to undelete or even reopen.

---

*: that is a bit inherent to tutorials though: they exist to show you how to do one specific thing. If a tutorial for an XML parsing library would have to start with explaining what bits are, then building up to bytes, characters, encodings and filesystems, it would become a book, and not a tutorial.

Comment: What points he raised looked me important. I'm even not interested in the answers he got on that question.

Comment: The points are very interesting, but not answerable on SO.